# is it the correct way of coding in jquery to assign textbox values to labels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have 2 textboxes and two labels . im assigning two textboxes values to two labels . is it the correct way of coding?

```
$(function () 
 { 
     $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= Label1.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
      $("#<%= TextBox2.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= Label2.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 $(function () 
 { 
     $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= Label1.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
 });
```

**Edit:**
For handling multiple textboxes:-

```
    $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>,#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>").keyup(function() {
           //Your code here..
    });
```

Comment: how  to add one more textbox ..
 $(function () 
 { 
     $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID,TextBox2.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= Label1.ClientID,Label2.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
 });

Comment: $(function () 
 { 
     $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>,#<%= TextBox2.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= Label1.ClientID%>,#<%= Label2.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
 }); 

while changing textbox1 ..its updating both labels. i just want to update one by one

Comment: @KikkiriPriya - Yes obviously it will update both since you have written a single event handler and it is assigning `$(this).val()` which is nothing but the textbox which is raising the event. If you want to update them separately, you should write two separate events for both textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to emit the dynamic value of the ID attribute in your HTML like so:

```
$('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text($(this).val());
```

You should adopt this way of working everywhere in your client script blocks (e.g. in your `keyup` event above as well)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>').keyup(function () { 
 $('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: $(function () 
 { 
     $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= Label1.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
      $("#<%= TextBox2.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= Label2.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
 }); 

im using like this..is this the correct way

Comment: Use this for multiple textbox `$("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>,#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>").keyup` @KikkiriPriya

Answer (score 0):

code for assigning multiple texboxes values to multiple labels. if any code redundancy is ther . plz let me know ...

```
 $(function () 
 { 
     $("#<%= TextMonday.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= LMonday.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     });
      $("#<%= TextTuesday.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= LblTuesday.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
     $("#<%= Textwednesday.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= LblWednesday.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
     $("#<%= TextThursday.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= LblThursday.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
     $("#<%= TextFriday.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= LblFriday.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
      $("#<%= TextSataurday.ClientID%>").keyup(function ()
     { 
         $("#<%= LblSataurday.ClientID%>").text($(this).val()); 
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: I don't think we can reduce the code since all the textboxes and their respective labels are different. What you were trying to achieve with comma separated textbox can't be used here since all the labels are different.